# How to cast Any to Array[T] maintaining Scala's invariance for arrays

Tags: arrays, scala, reflection

I tried to implement the following function maintaining Scala's invariant view over the JVM arrays:

```scala
def cast[T](a: Any): Option[Array[T]] = ???
```

That is, given:

```scala
class Foo
class Bar extends Foo
```

I want the following examples to return `Some`:

```scala
val arr1: Any = Array(new Bar)
cast[Bar](arr1) // OK

val arr2: Any = Array(1, 2, 3)
cast[Int](arr2) // OK

val arr3: Any = Array("a", "b", "c")
cast[String](arr3) // OK
```

For the following one, instead, I want it to return None:

```scala
val arr: Any = Array(new Bar)
cast[Foo](arr1) // I want it to be None

val arr2: Any = Array(List(new Bar))
cast[List[Foo]](arr2) // this must be None too!
```

I tried through reflection using `ClassTag/TypeTag` with no luck, but since I'm no reflection expert I could be missing something.

P.S.: I know that having `Any` there, is a bad practice but, please, try to see the question *academically*. You know, just to find out if there's a way to do it and how to.

**Update**: The solution provided below still does not work for `Array(List(new Bar))` because of type erasure.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are after:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def cast[T](a: Any)(implicit ct: ClassTag[Array[T]]): Option[Array[T]] = ct.unapply(a)
```

In the REPL:

```
scala> val x: Any = Array(1, 2, 3)
x: Any = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> val y = cast[Int](x)
y: Option[Array[Int]] = Some([I@7a8f55c)

scala> val z = cast[String](x)
z: Option[Array[String]] = None
```

**The solution above doesn't keep invariance; to do it the best way I found so far is this:**

```
def cast[T](in: Any)(implicit ct: ClassTag[Array[T]]): Option[Array[T]] = 
  if (ct.runtimeClass == in.getClass) ct.unapply(in) else None
```

Not sure how nice it is but it works:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Foo
class Bar extends Foo

val x: Any = Array(new Bar)

val y = cast[Foo](x)
val z = cast[Bar](x)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Foo
defined class Bar
x: Any = Array(Bar@6109a8cc)
y: Option[Array[Foo]] = None
z: Option[Array[Bar]] = Some([LBar;@7ccebaae)
```

Comment: Nope! Your implementation still fails to maintain Arrays' invariance. I edited my question to clarify what I want. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I see, sorry, I didn't notice that bit of your requirements. It's quite tricky to do that indeed!

Comment: Is the fact that you handle `Any` as an argument a requirement? I think it would make it easier if we could use some type information on the parameter, i.e. defining the function as `def cast[S, T](in: S): Option[Array[T]] = ???`. Obviously then we need a way to make it nicer to use but that's a separate issue. Otherwise I am thinking that it is not only tricky but pretty much impossible as there is no way to know that the types in the array are more specific but only to know that we can assign the parameter to such an array reference (i.e. losing invariance).

Comment: I updated my question. I just want to find out if there's a way to do it starting from `Any`. I suspect there's no way but I just wanted to be sure by asking it  here.

Comment: I added another solution to my answer, not sure how I like it but dealing with `Any` there's not that much you can do I guess.

Comment: If you have `val x: Any = Array(List(new Bar))` and cast it as in `val y = cast[List[Foo]]` the result is `Some` while it should be `None`, so it's still not working for nested types because of type erasure.